# Is it always possible to get from a set to another inside the universe?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

With an example:

We have $C\cap (A\cup B)$.
[image: set]
And we want to get to any other "state" (I don't know the actual term) by using set theory operations. Say we want to get to the blue area of $(A\cap B - C) \cup (B \cap C - A)$. Is this possible to do, regardless of the combination we might want?

Please do tell me if this is too vague or unclear. In few words, is there a finite number of operations that take a state in the universe and take it to *any* other state?

Comment: Yes. Any "region" is a union of sets of the shape $A^i\cap B^j \cap C^l$ where each of $i$, $j$, $k$ is either blank or the complement operation. Similar comments can be made if we start say with sets $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: "Please do tell me if this is too vague or unclear." Yes, it is. What is a set-theoretic operation? Without a precise description of that, I do not see how one can address the question. For instance, I assume $X=C\cap(A\cup B)$ is given, and you want to apply your operations to $X$, but not to $A$, $B$, or $C$. Otherwise, what is the point of even mentioning that we "have" $X$?